# Timeout reached cancel process

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making an application Bot and I want the Bot to automatically stop the application process if the client didn't send any message in last 15 min no matter if its the first, second or last question

```
if payload.emoji.name == '':
                await payload.member.send(frage1)
                answer1 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage2)
                answer2 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage3)
                answer3 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage4)
                answer4 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage5)
                answer5 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage6)
                answer6 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage7)
                answer7 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                YesOrNo = await payload.member.send('Fertig! Bist du sicher, dass du deine Bewerbung abschicken willst?')
                await YesOrNo.add_reaction('✅')
                await YesOrNo.add_reaction('❌')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the problem by using a try-except construct and a for loop so whenever the 15 minutes are over it will then pass an asyncio.TimeoutError and cancel the process.

```
if payload.emoji.name == '':
        frageList = [frage1, frage2, frage3, frage4, frage5, frage6, frage7]
        anwortList = []

        for i in frageList:
            try:
                Embed = discord.Embed(
                    color=discord.Colour.light_grey(),
                    description=f'**{i}**\n '
                )
                await payload.member.send(embed=Embed)
                anwortList.append(await self.client.wait_for('message', timeout=900.0, check=check))
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await payload.member.send('Bewerbung wurde unterbrochen!')
                return
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how you can do multiprocessing with the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module:**

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def stop_process(minutes):
    sleep(minutes*60)
    # Code to stop the process

Timer = Thread(target=stop_process)

Timer.start()
```

Comment: Thanks. For the answer, I think this isn't really useful, because it's based on the Discord API. If a Client didn't send an message in 15 min then it would cancel it. So I'm looking for something that can check the time and if the client send a message.

Comment: @ItzBen I see. In my earlier comment: What is the code to stop the process?